# Can I reset media permissions with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is the media's *"Reset permission"* which is available on page reload something I can control or trigger in JavaScript?

[image: Camera Microphone Reset Permissions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the browser's security model for microphone and camera access are outside of JavaScript. All JavaScript can do is request access to these resources, what happens afterward is left for the browser manufactures to implement to protect their users.